# iOS 10 people album: How to change the name of a person

Tags: photos.app, ios

I added a name for a person in the people album, but  there was a typo. Now it says Davr instead of Dave. It bugs the heck out of me. How can I change the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the name:

1. Open the Person (tap `Davr`)
2. Tap their name in the top, center of the screen (`Davr` in bold)
3. Change it's value.

Comment: On a related note, is it possible to change the photo that shows up as the "profile" for the person? (The one used in the list of people) It appears to have chosen a random one during the initial person creation and provides no option to change it.

Comment: Figured it out! Apparently this is called the "Key Face". Open person, select photo (select not open!), press arrow send button, choose option "Set Key Face".